# Map number to corresponding letter

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am writing on an application that is designed to be used with only a remote control.

I want to be able to go to a certain letter of my ListView with the number pad on the remote (using the corresponding letters printed on the buttons), for example:

- 2 = A, B or C
- 3 = D, E or F

At the moment I have it working with the first letter so 2 is pressed, it scroll the ListView to the A's.

I would like to go one step further and have it work like an old cellphone texting. So if 2 is pressed once, it will go to A, if 2 is pressed again (within about 2 seconds) it will go to B, and so on.

I am not sure how I would go about doing this and maybe it is beyond the scope of my abilities to wrap my head around it. I would appreciate any tips or maybe some example code that you may have used in the past to do something similar.

Here is my code at the moment, that goes to the first letter only:

```
Sub doLookup(ByVal input As String)
    For i As Integer = 0 To Showslist.Items.Count - 1
        Dim selected As Object = Showslist.Items.Item(i)
        Dim name As String = selected.name
        name = name.ToLower
        If name.StartsWith(input.ToLower) Then
            Showslist.SelectedIndex = i
            Showslist.ScrollIntoView(Showslist.SelectedItem)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Showslist_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Showslist.KeyUp

    Case Key.Return
        Case Key.D2
            doLookup("a")
            Exit Select
        Case Key.D3
            doLookup("d")
            Exit Select
        Case Key.D4
            doLookup("g")
            Exit Select
        Case Key.D5
            doLookup("j")
            Exit Select
        Case Key.D6
            doLookup("m")
            Exit Select
        Case Key.D7
            doLookup("p")
            Exit Select
        Case Key.D8
            doLookup("t")
            Exit Select
        Case Key.D9
            doLookup("w")
            Exit Select
        Case Key.D1
            doLookup("1")
            Exit Select
        Case Key.D0
            Showslist.SelectedIndex = 0
            Showslist.ScrollIntoView(Showslist.SelectedItem)
            Exit Select

    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to think about the problem is to understand the current state of the key presses.  Each number key from #2 to #8 has three states (key.D2, “a”, “b”, “c”) (key.D3, “d”, “e”, “f”) except for the #9 key which has four states (key.D9, “w”,”x”,”y”,”z”)*

**Assuming a U.S English keyboard.

My solution is to store which key was pressed in a private variable.  I also store how many times that key has been pressed.

```
Private currentKey As Key
Private currentKeyPresses As Integer
```

Use the `Mod` operator to keep the number in the correct range

```
currentKeyPresses = (currentKeyPresses + 1) Mod 3
```

Now pressing the #2 key cycles through the values 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2 etc.
When a new number key is pressed, reset the `currentKey` and `currentKeyPresses` variables.

```
currentKey = e.Key
currentKeyPresses = 0
```

I put the state storage code in the KeyDown event, and modified the KeyUp event code to lookup the correct letter for each keypress.

**Code**

```
  Private currentKey As Key
  Private currentKeyPresses As Integer
  Private currentLetter As String
  Private letters As String = "abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvwxyz"

  Private Sub Showslist_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Showslist.KeyDown
    If currentKey = e.Key Then
      If currentKey = Key.D9 Then
        ' the D9 key contains (4) letters (WXYZ)
        currentKeyPresses = (currentKeyPresses + 1) Mod 4

      Else
        ' assumes there are only three letters per key
        ' e.g D2 contains (3) letters (ABC)
        currentKeyPresses = (currentKeyPresses + 1) Mod 3
      End If

    Else
      ' this is the first time using that digit key
      currentKey = e.Key
      currentKeyPresses = 0

    End If

  End Sub

  Private Sub Showslist_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Showslist.KeyUp
    Dim currentLetter As String = ""

    Select Case e.Key
      Case Key.Return
      Case Key.D2
        currentLetter = GetLetterForDKey(0, currentKeyPresses)
      Case Key.D3
        currentLetter = GetLetterForDKey(3, currentKeyPresses)
      Case Key.D4
        currentLetter = GetLetterForDKey(6, currentKeyPresses)
      Case Key.D5
        currentLetter = GetLetterForDKey(9, currentKeyPresses)
      Case Key.D6
        currentLetter = GetLetterForDKey(12, currentKeyPresses)
      Case Key.D7
        currentLetter = GetLetterForDKey(15, currentKeyPresses)
      Case Key.D8
        currentLetter = GetLetterForDKey(18, currentKeyPresses)
      Case Key.D9
        currentLetter = GetLetterForDKey(21, currentKeyPresses)
      Case Key.D1
        doLookup("1")
      Case Key.D0
        Showslist.SelectedIndex = 0
        Showslist.ScrollIntoView(Showslist.SelectedItem)
        Exit Select

    End Select
    doLookup(currentLetter)
  End Sub

  Private Function GetLetterForDKey(startPosition As Integer, pressCount As Integer) As String

    Return letters.Substring(startPosition + pressCount, 1)

  End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a stopwatch

```
private StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();

Private Sub Showslist_KeyUp 
{
    sw.Stop();
    bool secondary = (sw.ElasedMillseconds > 0 and sw.ElasedMillseconds < 200);
    sw.Restart();
    ....
```